# Missing data on form submit: several forms in one table

Tags: html, webforms

I have a complex screen, which uses a listed of nested tables and several forms respective `ajaxSubmit`.

Although I believed that the issues was initial caused by jQuery, I had to find out that my HTML structure was causing issues. My initial structure was:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <form id="foo1" ..>
            <td><input ..></td>
            <td><input ..></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <form id="foo2" ..>
            <td><input ..></td>
            <td><input..></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works in IE8 and Chrome 11, but doesn't in FF3.6 and 4 respective Safari 5.0.4.

*Thanks everyone for you help and sorry for pointing in the wrong direction!*

Comment: You can skip the form before #, jQuery will use the document.getElementById if supplied with just a #id selector and that is the fastes selector you can have. I do not know if it can optimize away form from it in your code.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#allCategories').html(response);`?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: sorry, that was my mistake due to copy & paste

Comment: *" gives me an empty content"* - what does this mean? Your Ajax response is empty?

Comment: What I mean is that `alert($("form#sc" + id).serialize())` outputs an empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was supported in the old HTML specifications or at least tolerated. This changed in the later implementations. Hence one should either:

a) use several tables (one per form)

```
<form id="foo1">
    <table ..>
    </table>
</form>
<form id="foo2">
    <table ..>
    </table>
</form>
```

b) use DIVs instead of tables

Comment: It was never supported or tolerated by old HTML specifications, only by some implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a scoping issue. Try:

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function updateCategory(id) {
    var form = $('#sc' + id);

    form.ajaxSubmit({
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        url: '?action=modCat',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#allCategories').html(content);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately the behavior remains the same: works correctly after initial page load, but fails on later attempts.

Comment: @MrG *"works correctly after initial page load"* - what do you mean by that? Are you calling `serialize()` on page load?

Comment: When I load the website by surfing to `http://server/url` all forms can be submitted and refresh for example the content of `#allCategories` correctly. But if I try to submit any of the forms once again, it transfers no data although the HTML is valid and the form contains fields & values. I assume that something within the selector goes wrong, because if I insert an `alert($("form#sc" + id).serialize())` before the `ajaxSubmit` it outputs an empty alert.

Comment: @MrG Try this: `alert($("#sc" + id).length)` - if this alerts zero, then there is no element with such an ID on the page...

Comment: @Šime: Works (like the code) in IE8 and Chrome 11, but doesn't in FF3.6 and 4 respective Safari 5.0.4. FF and Safari only have the error after AjaxSubmit, which makes it really weird. Many thanks for your help!